# Google Chrome: Change location of URL Popup on mouseover

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome, when Chrome is running in full-screen, the URL pops up in the middle of the screen, like so:

[image: URL and other information pops up in the middle of the screen]

This is really annoying, and I wondered if anyone has some insight on how to change where it is? When not in full-screen, it looks like this:

[image: URL pops up in the bottom left-hand corner]

This does not cover the middle of the screen, so that is fine.

A little more information: I am seeing this on Windows 7, with Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no option to change this behavior, as can be seen [`here`](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/FtD7qjochgw) and [`here`](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qT5bY3mgpaM).